# Error when using "ResultPath" field in map state Iterator? "The field 'ResultPath' is not supported by Step Functions"

Tags: amazon-web-services, iterator, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I keep receiving the error, "The field 'ResultPath' is not supported by Step Functions" whenever I use "ResultPath" in the following code:

```
{
  "StartAt": "OuterFunction",
  "States": {
    "OuterFunction": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "GetIteration",
        "States": {
          "GetIteration": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
            "Next": "ReadDynamoDB"
          },
          "ReadDynamoDB": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",

            "Parameters": {
              "TableName": "TestTable",
              "Key": {
                "Keyword": "$.iteration"
               },
              "ResultPath": "$.dynamoDBResult"
            },
            "Next": "DoWork"
          },
          "DoWork": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "InputPath": "$.dynamoDBResult",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "StateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states:46372839402:stateMachine:do-work",
              "Input.$": "$.dynamoDBResult"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

For each iteration, it's intended to go out to a DynamoDB table, get an item corresponding to a key string, and send that item elsewhere to have more work done. However, whenever I try to save my code, I get a message telling me that "ResultPath" is not supported, and the step function will not run. I'm very confused, as I see many examples of people using "ResultPath" online. Is this because I am using it within an iterator? How else might I be able to pass the input of each iteration between tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're including `ResultPath` inside the `Parameters`, when it should be outside.

See this example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ddb.html

```
    "Read Next Message from DynamoDB": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "TransferDataRecords-DDBTable-3I41R5L5EAGT",
        "Key": {
          "MessageId": {"S.$": "$.List[0]"}
        }
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.DynamoDB",
      "Next": "Send Message to SQS"
    }
```

This means your code should be:

```
I keep receiving the error, "The field 'ResultPath' is not supported by Step Functions" whenever I use "ResultPath" in the following code:

{
  "StartAt": "OuterFunction",
  "States": {
    "OuterFunction": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "GetIteration",
        "States": {
          "GetIteration": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "ResultPath": "$.iteration",
            "Next": "ReadDynamoDB"
          },
          "ReadDynamoDB": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:getItem",

            "Parameters": {
              "TableName": "TestTable",
              "Key": {
                "Keyword": "$.iteration"
               }
            },
            "ResultPath": "$.dynamoDBResult",
            "Next": "DoWork"
          },
          "DoWork": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "InputPath": "$.dynamoDBResult",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
            "Parameters": {
              "StateMachineArn":"arn:aws:states:46372839402:stateMachine:do-work",
              "Input.$": "$.dynamoDBResult"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```